# Append HTML element within another HTML element

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm trying to append an HTML menu into an HTML element with JavaScript. The code works but it just straight up outputs as text and not as HTML elements.

**Javascript Code:**

```js
const mainMenu = `
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">SHOP</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">CONTACT US</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">LOGIN</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>`

document.querySelector("main").prepend(mainMenu)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Adding a DOM Element</title>
  <script type="module" src="script.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>
  <Header>
    <h1>ADDING TO A DOM ELEMENT</h1>
  </Header>
  <main>
    <h3>This is a h2 heading of some kind</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium
      quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus.
      Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet.
      Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, sit amet adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum.
      Nam quam nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus. Nullam quis ante. Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus tincidunt. Duis leo. Sed fringilla
      mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna. Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nunc,</p>
  </main>
</body>

</html>
```

**IT OUTPUTS THIS:**

[image: Append OUTPUT]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `insertAdjacentHTML` like this :

```js
const mainMenu = `
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">SHOP</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">CONTACT US</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">LOGIN</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>`

document.querySelector("main").insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin', mainMenu)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Adding a DOM Element</title>
  <script type="module" src="script.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>
  <Header>
    <h1>ADDING TO A DOM ELEMENT</h1>
  </Header>
  <main>
    <h3>This is a h2 heading of some kind</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium
      quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus.
      Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet.
      Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, sit amet adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum.
      Nam quam nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus. Nullam quis ante. Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus tincidunt. Duis leo. Sed fringilla
      mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna. Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nunc,</p>
  </main>
</body>

</html>
```

If you want to change the position of the inserted HTML you can change the first parameter :

- **'beforebegin**' : Before the element itself.
- **'afterbegin'** : Just inside the element, before its first child.
- **'beforeend'** : Just inside the element, after its last child.
- **'afterend'** : After the element itself.

[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML)

Comment: @Namysh and prepend() doens't work because of the linebreaks?

Comment: @Alex `Prepend` take set of Node or DOMString therefore, passing a string in parameter is equivalent as a DOMString thus, it displays the content as text. On the other hand `insertAdjacentHTML` take a string, it parses it and it inserts the resulting node in the DOM

Answer (score 0):

Use innerHTML,

```
document.querySelector("main").innerHTML+=mainmenu
```